# How to specify a CIDR block that covers only one address?

Tags: networking, cidr

When configuring an AWS routing table, I want to enter the destination address `A.B.C.D`. In the routing table, I can select either `A.B.C.D/28` or  `A.B.C.D/32`.

**Which of them means `A.B.C.D` only (only this one address)?**

My answer: `A.B.C.D/32`

Justification: The suffix (`/28`, `/32`) describes how many bits in the address are fixed. With `/28`, bits 29 through 32 can vary (see image below), whereas with `/32` all 32 bits are fixed.

[image: Fixed and variable bits]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In most modern routers (post 1998) have classless routing, (CIDR)
in classless routing is a single IP address 1.2.3.4 equivalent to 1.2.3.4/32

in classfull routing you have 3 classes A B and C (technically D and E also)
all class A addresses are a /8 CIDR class B is a /16 and class C is a /24